# Is it possible to cache MTLLibrary or MTLFunction?

Tags: metal

I can not find out how to save MTLLibrary or MTLFunction object to a specific file on disk (how am I supposed to get its binaries?). 
I'm creating .metal file, which is later compiled with `newLibraryWithSource` function.
I don't want to use separate `metal` compiler or XCode. In OpenGL there is `glGetProgramBinary()` function which does exactly what I want - is there something similar in MetalAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some research. It is not possible. External `metal` compiler is necessary to get binary shaders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's now possible to cache pipeline objects through Metal Binary Archives.

Additionally, it supports serialization and deserialization from a file. This file is a compiled binary shader that you create using the `MTLBinaryArchive` instance's `serializeToURL` method.

Answer (score -1):

So, a couple of things here:

1. Xcode makes building a .metallib easy. Just add a .metal file to your target, and it will build a default.metallib for your target along with the more traditional CPU binary.  Note that this thing is not a binary in the purest sense. There will have to be some compilation process to reduce the IR down to a machine specific binary.
2. Metal keeps a compiler cache of kernels that have already been compiled. The first time you build a shader, you'll spend some time on it.  To reduce this time hugely, build a .metallib per (1) above.  The second time you use the same shader, the compilation may hit the cache, in which case the binary is simply retrieved.  At least in my experience the compilation time can be mostly avoided by prewarming your GPU code by running it once on a dummy data set before the real time needs occur.

The real latencies are usually around allocating too much memory for MTLResources and keeping the GPU busy. You can do much more to improve performance by using a MTLHeap to alias multiple allocations to the same storage, and making sure that your next frame is committed before the current one is complete.  Allowing the GPU clock to slew down is incredibly expensive.